# JMS QPID handle reconnect

Tags: java, jms, qpid

I'm using JMS with QPID and wondering how to configure a reconnect if the broker cannot be reached anymore:

```
try (Connection connection = jmsFactory.createConnection(); Session session = connection.createSession()) {
            Queue queue = session.createQueue("queue:testQueue");
            Topic topic = session.createTopic("topic:testTopic");
            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("toQueue");
            TextMessage message2 = session.createTextMessage("toTopic");

            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
            producer.send(message);
            MessageProducer producer2 = session.createProducer(topic);
            producer2.send(message2);
            MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
            consumer.setMessageListener(new MessageListener() {

                @Override
                public void onMessage(Message message) {
                    try {
                        String content = extractBody(message);
                        System.out.println("From: " + message.getJMSDestination() + " Content: " + content);
                        message.acknowledge();
                    } catch (JMSException e) {
                        System.out.println("CANNOT GET CONTENT= " + e);
                    }
                }
            });
            connection.start();
            consumer.close();
  }catch ...
```

If the broker is not reachable anymore I would like to reconnect until the broker is back up again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to [Qpid JMS](http://qpid.apache.org/components/jms/index.html) then the client provides a failover transport that handles automatic reconnection for you so that your code wouldn't need to do anything.  The [documentation](http://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-jms-0.38.0/docs/index.html#failover-configuration-options) explains how to configure this, basically you modify your URI to wrap the host information with the failover tag:

```
 failover:(amqp://123.0.0.123:5672)
```

Comment: So I've to use this failover tag as remote url like `factory.setRemoteURI("failover:(amqp://123.0.0.123:5672)");` ?

Comment: Follow the documentation to use failover, you can use the setRemoteURI option or just create the ConnectionFactory with the desired URI